# Domotics connectivity options for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, rfid

I would like to explore the connectivity options for domotics software to connect hardware on a house compatible to iOS (iPhone/iWatch/iPad).

My first thoughts go to RFID tags applied to the devices or hardware transmitting Wi-Fi signal. However I am not sure that iOS is a system "open" enough to receive external signals.

For example when developing an App is not possible to let it access the main background thread whilst in background so it would be difficut to receive notifications from external hardware. My solution would be to send those notification to the device using the push notification system and paired to a server.

Could anyone help me clarify the reality of this?

Any useful link or resources? What are the latest advances as of iOS 8? And what are the best practices for this type of problems? What are the SDKs available for RFID?

Comment: `RFID` is only available on the iPhone 6 and is not accessible via the iOS SDK. So you as a developer can not acces the `RFID` for now.

Comment: Thanks. Are there some docs on how to implement a domotic hardware system compatible with iPhone 6 RFID receiver? Or for domotic application some other communication protocol is more appropriate (Eg. sending push notifications to the App via a server - where the server receives signals from a computer in the house connected to the domotic hardware)

Comment: Why do people vote to close this question? I am asking for a programming related question.. In other words is there an SDK for domotic hardware on iOS?

Comment: Asking for off site resources is offtopic for Stackoverlfow and asking for mest practices is going to yield only opinionated answer (also of topic).

Comment: Also you can not use the `RFID` hardware in the iPhone 6 as stated in my first comment. Push notification can of course be sent, just read the Apple documentation on Push notification.